# Using resouce files for login control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to localize the standart ASP.NET login control.

I need to change the content of the resource file. Just installing the right language pack doesnt help here because I need some specific wording. Is there a chance to see and edit the resx file used by the login user control?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I did not find any way yet to localize the control.